# How to add a default text for unmatched intents on dialogflow?

Tags: botframework, dialogflow-es, googlebot, wit.ai

If an intent fails, how can I assign it to a default text response?

Bot: what are you looking for?
Me: HakunakjewbfeuqcjBWGFUWG

Bot will not understand this and throws an error right there! I want to add a default text to this."I am not sure what you said.Can you say that again?"

How to do this?
I have tried fall back intent.it works only one time.So thats not a proper solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you share the code you are using now? which would help us quickly reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it works only one time". What happens the second time?

Comment: The bot stops responding...

Answer (score 1):

You have it correct - set a Fallback Intent. If you need a specific "no match" response to only some portions of your conversation, you can use a context to match those portions.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

> Default fallback intent

To handle such ambiguous responses, you can set not only one but many different responses too which will appear randomly so the conversation's feel real too.
And Dialogflow has a default fall back Intent with pre-feeded Responses so all you have to do is enable it and train it according to your own phrases.

Answer (score 0):

You might have added `[LuisIntent("None")]`, to redirect not understood intents use `[LuisIntent("")]` and have desired default message in the following method.
Else
you can redirect such gibberish text to none intent

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Default Fall Back intent or you could set an output context for the present intent to go to default fallback intent.